# Can EDA be used for asking a new question?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, exploratory-data-analysis

Data Analyst gets inspiration to ask a new question about the data, so the analyst begins the EDA on the same data set and goes through the 5 phases - Question; EDA; Modeling; Interpretation and Communication.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? If so, what is it?

Comment: classical hypothesis testing requires the hypotheses to random, but if the analyst chooses the hypothesis based on random data, we're no longer in that setting. This is called "data snooping". All the same, this is a subtle question. Many still do it, and I think some justification is that they may be finding questions that would have asked if they just had considered the problem more carefully to begin with.

Comment: Unless the view is taken that all hypotheses arise from pure thought alone, why shouldn't data analyses be accepted as a possible source of inspiration?

Comment: @Nick Cox It should be a source of inspiration but the inspiration should be tested subsequently using new data with confirmatory data analysis. If effects are strong enough and corrections for post-hoc testing are done, the same data used in EDA can be used for confirming (defined loosely) the conclusions.

Comment: I am all for further testing, naturally. I am just against any idea that learning from data is bad or dubious; that learning can include new hypotheses.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation(s) and response(s) - Ben, David & Nick